# AWS RedisConnectionException: No connection is available to service this operation. SocketClosed Exception

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, redis-cache, cachingframework.redis

Suddenly we started getting below mentioned Exception when hitting `Redis Cache (AWS)`.
It was working fine in the past.
We have seen in that **Current Connections count** for Redis node goes on increasing.

> No Connection available" exception while accessing redis. Following is the exception -
>   "No connection is available to service this operation: GET xxxxx; SocketClosed on xxxxx/Interactive, origin: ProcessReadBytes, input-buffer: 0, outstanding: 0, last-read: 69s ago, last-write: 69s ago, unanswered-write: 2630s ago, keep-alive: 60s, pending: 0, state: ConnectedEstablished, in: 0, ar: 0, last-heartbeat: 0s ago, last-mbeat: 0s ago, global: 0s ago: RedisConnectionException
>   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in c:\code\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 2027 at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in c:\code\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\RedisBase.cs:line 81
>   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.StringGet(RedisKey key, CommandFlags flags) in c:\code\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\RedisDatabase.cs:line 1647
>   at CachingFramework.Redis.Providers.RedisCacheProvider.GetObject[T](String key)
>   at NetCoreUtilities.CachedUserObjectRedis.Get() in /codebuild/output/src803013914/src/NetCoreUtilities/CachedObjects/CachedUserObject.cs:line 63
>   at NetCoreUtilities.CachedUserObject.GetCachedUserObject(ElasticacheHelper elasticacheHelper, Int64 userID) in /codebuild/output/src803013914/src/NetCoreUtilities/CachedObjects/CachedUserObject.cs:line 82
>   at GetChildCategoriesAndAssets.Function.FunctionHandler(JObject input, ILambdaContext context) in /codebuild/output/src803013914/src/DIT Framework/users/GetChildCategoriesAndAssets.cs:line 54
>   at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )"

We are using `.Net framework 4.5` and `StackExchange.Redis 1.2.1`, we tried using latest version of `StackExchange.Redis`, but its seems it does not support `.Net framework 4.5`.

What should we do without changing current .Net Framework of the Application? Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Please your working if you did

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Issue has been resolved for now.

There is some issue in old version of Redis which although the timeout set, is not closing the connections.

1. Upgraded Redis version in AWS console. (`Redis5.0`)
2. Updated `CachingFramework.Redis` version to `11.1.0`
3. Updated `StackExchange.Redis` library to `2.0.601`
4. Set Timeout value for Parameter Group set back to 0 (Default).

Note: For this, we have updated .Net Framework as well.

Comment: Actually no this isn't resolved and is an ongoing bug but should be soon. See: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/pull/137